# az vmss update for updating the DNS

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VMSS on Azure and I need to change the DNS server of it. I have found the Azure CLI command for this but I can't figure it out how the final form of it.
This is what I have:

```
az vmss update -n myVmss --set virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].dnsSettings
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`az vmss update -n myVmss --set virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].dnsSettings='{"dnsServers":["10.0.0.5", "10.0.0.6"]}'`

If you are using `--set` you need to supply the entire object. You may need to escape the double quotes.

`...dnsSettings="{\"dnsServers\":[\"10.0.0.5\", \"10.0.0.6\"]}"`

If the DNS settings object isn't empty, you could also do this:

`az vmss update -n myVmss --add virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].dnsSettings.dnsServers "10.0.0.5"`

Comment: Thank a lot, man! That helped me to resolve my problem.

Best regards!